# Dependencies not being resolved using package (package not being respected?)

Tags: requirejs

I have a module that is defined and has it's own dependencies (resolved locally)

When using require in the browser, it works fine.
However, when I setup for testing, I use a package to resolve back to my source code

```
packages: [
    {
        name:"packageSource",
        location:( process.argv[2] == "html-cov" ) ? "../../CodeCoverage" : "../../src",
        main:"packageSource"
    }
]
```

This works for all of the top level files being required in, however when they require in their own modules the path's aren't being resolved properly.

Top level file (working):

```
var controller = require('packageSource/modules/moduleA/ParentController');
```

Within that file I do:

```
var rowController = require('./components/simple/controller.js');
```

It should call to: src/modules/moduleA/components/simple/controller.js

Instead it calls to packageSource/components/simple/controller.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few developers looking at this, we finally figured it out.

It's because of the .js in the path. Probably because of the package definition, when you give it a literal file, it tries to resolve it literally, not using it's existing definitions.

Removing the .js fixed it.